# Trying to understand "syntax" keyword in Isabelle/HOL

Tags: syntax, isabelle

I am trying to understand implementation of Linear logic in Isabelle/HOL: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/hvg/Isabelle/dist/library/Sequents/Sequents/ILL.html For what does `syntax` keyword stand for, what is meant by code:

```
syntax
  "_Trueprop" :: "single_seqe" ("((_)/ ⊢ (_))" [6,6] 5)
  "_Context"  :: "two_seqe"   ("((_)/ :=: (_))" [6,6] 5)
  "_PromAux"  :: "three_seqe" ("promaux {_||_||_}")
```

Where can I find documentation for the `syntax` keyword? I have found exhaustive documentation about `infixr` and translation rules in Lecture Notes in Computer Science Vol 828. But I can not find similar documentation about `syntax`.

Answer (score 2):

This is described in the reference manual in section 8.5.2 (as of Isabelle 2016-1): "Raw syntax and translations".

The first line there means to add a syntax rule saying that `P ⊢ Q` parses to `_Trueprop P Q`. The next lines of `ILL.thy` give a `parse_translation`, described just afterwards in the same section of the reference manual. This translation tells Isabelle to translate `_Trueprop` to `K (single_tr Trueprop)` and `Trueprop` is declared as an uninterpreted constant at the top of the file. You'll see there's also a `print_translation`, which controls the pretty printer.